# How to create a set countdown timer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm attempting to create a countdown timer from a set time, say, 2 hours.

I have a button and a label and I'd like, when the button is pressed, for the timer to begin, being displayed after the "Time Remaining:" - if the button is pressed again, the timer resets.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
var itemClick = document.getElementById('item1');

itemClick.addEventListener('click', function(){
    itemHandler();
})

function itemHandler(){
    var label = document.getElementById('item1-label');
    if (label.innerHTML == "") { 
        label.innerHTML = "Time Remaining:"; 
    }
}
```

How exactly would I implement this?

Comment: So, what the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
function itemHandler(){
    var label = document.getElementById('item1-label');
    if (label.innerHTML == "") { 
        var countdown = 10;
        label.innerHTML = `Time Remaining: ${countdown}`;
        var countdownInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (countdown > 0) {
                label.innerHTML = `Time Remaining: ${countdown}`;
                countdown -= 1;
            }
        }, 1000); 
    } else {
        clearInterval(countdownInterval);
        label.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to have the countdown display in H:M:S, would you suggest I recreate the loop with a different interval for each hour, minute, and second?

Comment: @xstax No, I think it will be alright to use seconds as the duration and then convert and display the interval for each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

```
var timer = setInterval(timerCount, 1000);
var t = 10;
function timerCount() {
                
                t--;
                if (t < 0) {
                                console.log("times up");
                                clearInterval(timer);
                } else {
                                console.log(t);
                }
                
                
}
```

It's easiest way to make a countdown as far as I know (and I don't know much;-) )
You seem familiar with basic DOM manipulation, so I will leave the rest to you. Remember, to clear the interval, you have to first set it using a variable.